# Electron - How to add external files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I have an Electron app. I try to make the app open an .exe file. I created a directory in the root folder named `lib` and placed the .exe file there. In development, I have no problem opening the file by using `__dirname + '/lib/file.exe`, but when I package the app (using `yarn dist`), it does not open the exe file and there is no `lib` folder anymore on the `dist` folder.

I tried writing to console the default location using `console.log(__dirname)` and it outputs `\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asa` (which is a file).

How can I add an external file that can be accessed when the app is packaged?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Managed to solve it by using extraResources. Should be declared under build in your `package.json` file.

For example:

1. Create a new folder named extraResources adjacent to pacakge.json
2. Add the following code to your `package.json` file:

   ```
   "build": {
       "extraResources": ["./extraResources/**"]
   }
   ```
3. Then, you can access the files inside this folder by using `__dirname + '/../extraResources/'` from your main app.

Comment: use `process.resourcesPath` instead of `__dirname` for a more reliable cross-platform solution.

Comment: This worked for me:
```const path = require('path');
path.join(process.resourcePath, 'extraResources', 'filename');
```

Comment: Inside this ``extraResources`` directory I have a file timer.sh when I trying your method, then I am getting this error ```Uncaught Error: ENOENT, extraResources/timer.sh not found in /opt/ProjectName/resources/app.asar```

Comment: Thank you this really helped me a ton!

Comment: @americo there is a typo in your code, it should be `process.resourcesPath`.

Comment: How does this work during development though? These files don't seem to be copied when `electron .` is run in the cwd during development

Answer (score 40):

Add the following code to package.json:

```
 "build": {
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "./src/extraResources/",
        "to": "extraResources",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Then, you can access the files using

```
const configFile = path.join(path.dirname(__dirname), 'extraResources','config.json');
```

I use the following folders structure which allows me to run the app any way.

from project folder:
`node_modules\.bin\electron.cmd src\main\index.js`

from unpacked source
`dist\win-unpacked\app.exe check-for-update`

from installed folder
`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\app\app.exe`

```
+-- dist
|   +-- win-unpacked
|      +-- resources
|         +-- extraResources
|            config.json
+-- node_modules
+-- src 
|   +-- extraResources
|      config.json
|      someFile.js
|   +-- main
|      index.js
|   +-- render
|      index.js
```

Comment: Hi @swaroop-bekal, I tried it under windows but doesn't works.
The folder extraResources are correcty created but if I launch the application I have this messages: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '\extraResources\config.json'

Answer (score 9):

there I found a new solution, 
using electron-packager on Windows do not add the files into the resources folder at the end of the process.

So I added this command into the `package.json`

```
"build-win": "electron-packager . --platform=win32 --asar --prune --arch=ia32 --extra-resource=./extraResources/documents/QuickStartGuideWN-H1.pdf --extra-resource=./extraResources/MAC_drivers/MacOS10.14/ --icon=assets/alfa_a.ico --out ./dist --overwrite",
```

And now the files are insied the resource fodlder just add

```
--extra-resource=./extraResources/file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"build": {
    "extraResources": [{
        "from": "./public/assets/file.html",
        "to": "file.html",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }]}
```

**"./public/assets/file.html"**
This file existe in your develepmont directory, and it will be copied to resources folder **"C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Programs\softwarename\resources\file.html"**