# How to read a file from extraResources?

Tags: electron

I have a file that should be changable without needing to rebuild the project.
I'm therefore using the `extraResources` located in:

```
.
├── extraResources
│   └── flags.json
├── src
├── package.json
└── ...
```

For the build process my `package.json` contains the following:

```
{
    "build": {
        "extraResources": [
            "./extraResources/**"
        ]
    }
}
```

This part seems to work since in the build output I get the `extraResources` in `dist/win-unpacked/resources/extraResources/flags.json`.

The above was done following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46033483/2230045

I'm loading this file via:

```
const filepath = path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'extraResources', 'flags.json');
const data = fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf-8');
```

This works fine during debugging but after the build, it fails with:

> Uncaught Exception: Error: ENOENT, extraResources\flags.json not found
>   in C:\dev\MyProgram\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar

It is not clear to me why this is not working while it seemingly works for others.

Based on a hint from [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/1474#issuecomment-306033903) I tried using [hazardous](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hazardous) but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `appPath` is different:

- when you start your development server it is e.g. `C:\dev\MyProgram\dist`
- when you start the executable in the `packaged` directory it is e.g.
  `C:\dev\MyProgram\packages\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar`

  - and the extra resources that you specified are adjacent to `app.asar`
  - e.g. `C:\dev\MyProgram\packages\win-unpacked\resources\extraResources\flags.json`

An easy fix is to just delete the `asar` part from the path:

```js
const appPath = app.getAppPath().replace('app.asar', '');
const filepath = path.join(appPath, 'extraResources', 'flags.json');
```

This will work in both cases: i.e. when it does not exist in the path the path is not changed