# How to add config file into exe. build in electronjs

Tags: javascript, electron, config, electron-builder

In my project i have added a config file (JSON format)  for my static values. Problem is , project is working when i type **npm start**, but when i build exe (using **electron-builder .**), it is not working

[image: My folder structure]

According to this answer [Electron - How to add external files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022443/electron-how-to-add-external-files)
i change my package.json but it didn't work.  I have added my folder structure and package.json

[image]

This is the error i'm getting
[image]

Comment: Hint: In your packaged app files, look for a file called "app.asar", extract it to see which file are packaged correctly and which are not.

Comment: @aabuhijleh .. hey i extract it and config folder and default.json is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution npm config (https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) not working (https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/issues/403 )in electronjs. But after using this https://github.com/dw1284/electron-node-config it worked.